# Error I get: The method myMethod(int[]) is ambiguous for the type ArityMethod

Tags: java, ellipsis

What is the reason for getting an error while running this code,
I get an error when I run `myMethod()`

```
public class ArityMethod {
    
    public static void myMethod(int... arg){
          System.out.print("\nmyMethod1 : ");
          for (int i : arg) {
           System.out.print(i+", ");
          }
         }
         
         public static void myMethod(String... arg){
          System.out.print("\nmyMethod2 : ");
          for (String str : arg) {
           System.out.print(str +" ");
          }
         }
         
         public static void myMethod1(int a, float b, Object... arg){
          
          System.out.print("\nmyMethod3 a value : "+a);
          System.out.print("\nmyMethod3 b value : "+b);
          
          System.out.print("\nmyMethod3 : ");
          for (Object str : arg) {
           System.out.print(str.toString() +" ");
          }
         } 
         
         public static void main(String[] args) {
          myMethod(1,2,3,4,5);
          myMethod("hello", "welcome", "to", "Java Discover");
          myMethod1(100,3.0f, "hello", "welcome", "to", "Java Discover");
          myMethod(); 
         }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems obvious, no? `myMethod()` can refer to either the `myMethod(int... arg)`, doable by passing a `new int[0]`, as well as the `myMethod(String.. arg)` variant, by passing a `new String[0]`. Both are equally valid, so java doesn't know which one to call, and therefore refuses to compile your code.

You have <strike>two</strike> three solutions:

1. Just call the right one using an explicit array: `myMethod(new int[0])` to call m1, `myMethod(new String[0])` to call m2.
2. Fix your bad API design. As a rule you should never allow this. Either rename one or both of the `myMethod` names to disambiguate, or, ensure this overlap cannot occur, for example by having `void myMethod(int... arg) {}` as well as `void myMethod(String a, String... rest) {}`, thus ensuring that `myMethod()` can only refer to the `int...` variant.
3. Make an explicit no-args version: `void myMethod() { ... }`, this one will take precedence over the other two if you try to invoke `myMethod()`.

If you're writing such methods, go with option #2 or #3. If this is an academic exercise or you've been forced to deal with code that works like this, tell the author it's bad code, then use an explicit array.

EDIT: Added option #3 as per @Stephen C's comment.

Comment: That's a pretty detailed explanation. However, I think OP was only looking for the source of error, so the first 2 lines should've been good enough. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, calling myMethod() could refer to any of **myMethod(int... args)**, or **myMethod(String... args)**, and both have the same priority in this case. That's why you are getting this error.

For detailed explanation on var-args and overloading, please refer to  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-overloading-ambiguity-varargs-java/. It will help understand the var-args better.

Hope that clears!